# CSS selector to target the last of br-tags that appear in pairs within a p-tag?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to normalize the spacing between line-breaks and paragraphs in some text.

To do this I wish to collapse all line-breaks so that they yield no height in themselves, and then add margin-bottom to the last of two consecutive `<br>` tags.

Is there a css-selector that let's me select the last of `<br>` tags that appear in pairs within a `<p>`?

```
<p>
   Some text<br />
   Some more text<br /><br /> <!-- I wan't to target the last of these -->
   Even more text<br /> <!-- Not this one -->
</p>
```

I tried the following selectors, but no dice. It seems the + selector ignores the text and becomes to greedy.

```
p br {
    line-height: 0;
    height:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
}

p br + br {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/jqcyc/

Is this at all possible with the given markup, preferably without any javascript?

Answer (score 7):

Raw text is, in some way, *invisible* to CSS selectors. According to your HTML, CSS sees it as:

```
<p>
    <br />
    <br /><br /> <!-- I wan't to target the last of these -->
    <br /> <!-- Not this one -->
</p>
```

So every `<br />` but the first one is matched with the `p br + br` selector. There's no way to resolve your problem in the way you're approaching it (raw CSS).

Other approaches are **JavaScript** or **server-side** (whatever language you're using - PHP, Java etc.).

Answer (score 2):

If you're always going to have the same amount of `br` tags, you can use `br:nth-child(n)` to select them.

An example being: `br:nth-child(2){ height:12345px; }`

Answer (score 1):

There is no CSS only solution to do that. But you can add a class to the `<br />` elements that you want to select (and you avoid using two consecutive br's). Here is in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jqcyc/5/